# How to create a hyperlink to shared network directory or file?

Tags: html, windows, google-chrome

I've checked the following two related discussions:
1. [How do I make a hyperlink to a local executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815982/how-do-i-make-a-hyperlink-to-a-local-executable)
2. [An URL to a Windows shared folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796215/an-url-to-a-windows-shared-folder)
3. [File Url Cross Domain Issue in Chrome- Unexpected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060786/file-url-cross-domain-issue-in-chrome-unexpected)
4. [Firefox Links to local or network pages do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192080/firefox-links-to-local-or-network-pages-do-not-work)

The following links work when I visited the website on localhost. That is, `http://localhost`.

```html
<a href="\\172.21.1.123\DIR">A Shared Network Directory</a>
<a href="file://172.21.1.123\DIR">A Shared Network Directory</a>
<a href="file://///172.21.1.123\DIR">A Shared Network Directory</a>
```

But when I visited with `http://172.21.1.123`, all of above links have no response.
The debug console shows that `Not allowed to load local resource: file://172.21.1.123/DIR`.

Test Environment (Both of them have the same result.):
- Chrome 28.0.1500
- IE 10

If it is due to the security reason, any configuration to turn off? Or any idea?

Comment: It might be a port forwarding problem.

Comment: ^ Or a firewall and/or file sharing in windows is disabled

Comment: @lazyCrab Could you describe it in more details??

Comment: @DarkBee The network links work when I visited the website on localhost. I think not the firewall issue and it's certainly shared.

Comment: @KordanOu : What are the permisions on the share ?
Does everyone have read rights ? (The share permissions, not the NTFS ones)

Comment: @DarkBee he read right is open for all login users. All of them are Windows machines and logged in the remote server sharing the directory. (That means I could get into \\172.21.1.123\DIR directly by Windows explorer)

Comment: Seems its more likely a browser security setting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192080/firefox-links-to-local-or-network-pages-do-not-work

Comment: @DarkBee Still no luck...:(

Comment: I'd say install a webserver on the computer. Create a script that list the contents of the shared folder and output links like : http://X.X.X.X/DIR/file1.rar. Make sure port 80 is not blocked by the firewall of the host computer

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you cannot link to a network share from an external/hosted/live site is because of security features of latest browsers like Firefox.

You can only open local network shares from a local HTML document.

The only way around this is to install a plugin for your browser that removes or disables this security feature as far as I know.

Comment: You know any plugin to remove this type of security