# Relative Link To Local File

Tags: html, autorun

I have a local HTML file that we are using as a USB Menu - when the USB device is plugged in the webpage will automatically open and show our menu.

In our menu we have a link to our installer. When the user clicks the link it opens our installer window.

The code is:

```
<a href="file:///C:/Test_USB_Menu/src/Company Plugins.exe">Install Our Plugins</a>
```

The link works fine but we want to make the link to the file relative. Ie, make it;

```
<a href="file:///src/Company Plugins.exe">Install Our Plugins</a>
```

But when I change this the file no longer opens when I click the link. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Is it possible to have relative paths for files?

The folder structure is like so:

```
- Root USB
  - AUTORUN.html
  - src
     - Company Plugins.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to remove the prefix scheme. Try:

```
<a href="/src/Company Plugins.exe">Install Our Plugins</a>
```

You could also try a `.` operator to signify the current directory:

```
<a href="file:///./src/Company Plugins.exe">Install Our Plugins</a>
```

Comment: That works for Firefox and Chrome but not for IE. Any ideas what to do for IE?

Comment: Does it work in IE with the absolute path that you posted? If not, it is not a path issue. IE might also present quirks with .exe files in general (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815982/how-do-i-make-a-hyperlink-to-a-local-executable).