# cmd line executable web link without a seperate batch file

Tags: hyperlink, cmd, windows-7-x64

SO I want to have a web link that will- open up cmd.exe, take input from a user (store it in a variable for use later in the script), and then be able to execute a script, all these without a separate batch file being involved.

Basically : Click link ---> Cmd opens up and asks for input ----> takes input and executes a script.

Example: Click link ---> Cmd opens up and asks for Username ----> Looks up username from a directory.

I have no idea how to do this. Any ideas??

OS involved: Windows 7

Comment: The inverse is required often. http://superuser.com/questions/36728/can-i-launch-urls-from-command-line-in-windows But what you want seems undesirable

Comment: I have voted this up because it is an interesting question, but I agree with @ChristiaanWesterbeek that it is undesirable.

Comment: Looks similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815982/how-do-i-make-a-hyperlink-to-a-local-executable

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek I have no bad intentions. It's for internal company use only, to check for a person without manually opening up cmd prompt each time.